# My GET requests (with Guzzle) is not send until à shut down client serveur(EDIT:might block by another request?)

Tags: php, get, request, guzzle

I have two microservices, one is my main API who send à request to encode video,the other one is ( lets call if apiEncode) is a microservice who encode a video and call my main API when its done ( to update in db).

Here the issue, when i call my apiEncode, the video is encoded in 4 formats, each time i call with a get. But i have to shutdown my apiencode server to send request.

```
    $promises = [];
    $client = new Client();
    for ($i = $index; $i < sizeof($sizers); $i++) {
        $mp4Format = new X264();
        $mp4Format->setAudioCodec("aac");
        $video
            ->filters()
            ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension($values[$i], $keys[$i]))
            ->synchronize();
        $video
            ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
            ->save('frame.jpg');
        $video
            ->save($mp4Format, $directory . $source . '_' . $keys[$i] . '.mp4');
        $path = $directory . $source . '_' . $keys[$i] . '.mp4';
        $jwt = authenticateJwt($path);

       $promises = $client->requestAsync('GET', '192.168.197.133:8080/api/updateVideoFormat', [
            'headers' => [
                'PATH' => $directory . $source . '_' . $keys[$i] . '.mp4',
                "ID_VIDEO" => $id,
                'FORMAT' => $keys[$i],
                'JWT' => $jwt
            ]
        ]);

    }
    try {
        $results = Promise\settle($promises)->wait();
        error_log("ok");
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
}
```

Why the request is send when i shutdown the apiEncode serveur?
how could i fixe that

EDIT : 
It might be the first request who block the others? if yes, How could i stop block ? shut connexion ? dont wait response ?

Here my code API side,

```
 if (!empty($source)) {
        $httpcode = 200;
       $promise = $client->requestAsync('GET', '192.168.197.133:8081/api/encode', [
           'debug' => [true
       ],
            'headers' => [
                'Content_length'=> 1000,
                'Connexion'=>'close',
                'JWT' => $jwt,
                'PATH' => $path,
                'SOURCE' => $source,
                'ID_VIDEO' => $id,
            ]
        ])->wait();
    } else {
        $httpcode = 404;
        displayErrorJSON("Not found");
    }

    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        ->withStatus($httpcode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution:

Guzzle cant do fire and forget request.

So I setup a timeout request and it worked.
and don't need async.

```
$client->request('GET', '192.168.197.133:8080/api/updateVideoFormat', [
    'timeout' => 0.5,
    'headers' => [
        'PATH' => $directory . $source . '_' . $keys[$i] . '.mp4',
        "ID_VIDEO" => $id,
        'FORMAT' => $keys[$i],
        'JWT' => $jwt
    ]
]);
```